# How to get the text of a node without getting children's text nodes using PHP Simple DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm using PHP Simple DOM Parser librairy, and I have a little question..
I have to parse an HTML document which is like :

```html
<div>
  here the text I want
  <strong>another text</strong>
 </div>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to only get the text from the div tag (and not the text from the strong tag). Is that possible do to this automatically (without specify the location of the text) ?

Thanks in advance,

Jordan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the children of the `div` element, and look for text nodes (which will exclude `strong` and other elements):

```
$html = "<div>
  here the text I want
  <strong>another text</strong>
 </div>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
$text = "";
foreach($div->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) $text .= $node->nodeValue;
}
echo trim($text);
```

If the root element is not always `div`, but could be any element, then change the assignment to *$div* like this:

```
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->childNodes[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to tell you that the root node is not necessary a div tag, do you have a solution for this issue ? Thanks in advance

Comment: See the last paragraph I just added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !